# Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::authenticated()

Tags: php, laravel

I wanna use authenticated() in my login() return type. I wanna try to when user try to login via their phn_number they can login and it also check middleware / user_role. This part of code i write on autheticated() .  so my plan is when i login , the login() will return via the authenticated() also.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\SiteSettings;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;
use User;

class LoginController extends Controller
{


    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected function authenticated (Request $request, $user)
    {
        if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role->id == 1 ) {
            $this->redirectTo = route('admin.dashboard');

        } elseif(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role->id == 2 ) {
            $this->redirectTo = route('doctor.dashboard');

        } elseif(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role->id == 3 ) {
            $this->redirectTo = route('nurse.dashboard');

        } else {
            $this->redirectTo = route('search.doctor');
        }
    }

   // protected $redirectTo = $this->authenticated();

    public function __construct()
    {
         $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }


    public function field()
    {
        if (filter_var(request()->phn_number,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
            return 'email';
        }else{
            return 'phn_number';
        }
    }
    public function login()
    {
        // Check Right Position
      //  return $this->field();
        if (Auth::attempt([$this->field()=>request()->phn_number, 'password'=>request()->password ])){
           // Wanna Return Authenticated function
            //return redirect()->intended('/');
            return redirect()->intended($this->authenticated());
        }else{
            return redirect()->back()->withInput('phn_number');
        }
    }

}
```

So It's returned me Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::authenticated().
I also try to use

```
  return $this->authenticated();
```

It also give me error.

Comment: you shold pass that arguments. Ie: `$this->authenticated(request(), Auth:user())`, but you don't really needs that information in that function, just remove them `protected function authenticated () { //... }`

Answer (score 1):

The `authenticated()` method that overrides method on `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers` class, has 2 arguments you have to pass to, so change your `login()` method to this one:

```php
public function login(Request $request)
{
    // Check Right Position
    //  return $this->field();
    if (Auth::attempt([$this->field() => $request->phn_number, 'password' => $request->password])) {
        // Wanna Return Authenticated function
        //return redirect()->intended('/');
        return redirect()->intended(authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user()));
    } else {
        return redirect()->back()->withInput('phn_number');
    }
}
```

As you can see, we're calling `authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())` with 2 arguments instead of `authenticated()` with no arguments.

You can also rewrite your `authenticated` method and use `$user`, also no need to use `Auth::chcek()` because user is already authenticated when reaches this method:

```php
protected function authenticated (Request $request, $user)
{
    if ($user->role->id == 1) {
        $this->redirectTo = route('admin.dashboard');
    } else if($user->role->id == 2) {
        $this->redirectTo = route('doctor.dashboard');
    } else if($user->role->id == 3) {
        $this->redirectTo = route('nurse.dashboard');
    } else {
        $this->redirectTo = route('search.doctor');
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no requirement for the op to pass two arguments to the authenticated method. You can simply overridde it because AuthenticateUsers is just a trait. So if they just drop the $user argument and use Auth::user()  it should be fine. Same with the request, just use the facade like porloscerro said.

Comment: @AlexMac you're right, I tried to explain that why the op is getting this error, the `authenticated` method has been overridden with 2 args and should be call with 2 args. Or be overridden with no args and be called with no args too.

Comment: Yeah, sorry on mobile, I didn't see your update. I just wanted to point out op was dealing with a trait. Therefore, you could override everything if op really wanted to.